# How to validate and capture data corresponding to business hours as one input from two separate fields in Angular? (Reactive Forms)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[image]

So I want to create a reactive form on Angular which has its form group structured by default as follows (in my .ts file):

```
 constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder){}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createBusinessListingForm=this.fb.group({
     ................. 
     "businessHours":['',Validators.required],  
     ....................
    })
  }
```

I already have a bunch of other input fields captured in the form of text like name, location etc, alongside that I wish to add the business hours (as an array) which will must look like this on my browser (shown in the picture). But however, I need to make sure that the "from" and "to" hours drop-down option shows up only if the toggle option "Open" is enabled for that corresponding day (as shown in the picture) and also I need to validate the resulting data in my ts file. So being a newbie to Angular Reactive forms, I want to know how I can capture these days+hours details through my html template from the user and then validate those field(s) in the .ts file. (btw I use bootstrap for styling)

Answer (score 0):

## Capture Form Data with valueChanges

All you need to do is subscribe to the formControl responsible for the toggle button, and then if it gets `true`, show the `from` and `to` options.

Here is an example:

```js
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createBusinessListingForm = this.fb.group({
     ................. 
     "businessHours":['',Validators.required],  
     ....................
    })
    
    // now we want to check form control for toggle value
    
    this.createBusinessListingForm.get('businessHours').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      value && this.toggleHourRange()
    })
    // remember to choose the proper formControl to check its value changes
    
}


toggleHourRange() {
  // here you can add your logic
}
```

### Important Notes

- Remember to subscribe to the formContorl inside `ngOnInit` otherwise
  it might not work properly
- The Logic you want to implement to    show/hide the `from` and `to.`
  ranges can vary between using    `*ngIf` on your HTML file (which
  you need to change its value inside    the `toggleHourRange`
  function) OR you can add/remove them from your formArray.

**You can learn more about Angular Reactive Forms [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-forms-reactive-form-including-angular-material-and-custom-validator-9ef324cc3b08)**